# My bitcoin transaction does not exist in blockchain.info nor does it exist in any tx accelerator

Tags: lost-transactions, breadwallet

I sent bitcoin to myself using Breadwallet.

Before that, I went to my Breadwallet which I made a purchase from a few days ago and when I login it says something about a payment being rejected so I'm thinking I got refunded for the purchase I made.

I go and try to send myself the bitcoin to my main wallet and then it says there's a transaction error and it said I needed to synchronize the wallet with the block chain or something similar. After that happens, it shows me that my older payment has been sent and my newer transaction of me thinking it was a refund is also being processed and is stuck on 40% but when I try to track the transaction using blockchain.info using the transaction id it says the transaction can't be found. This is the transaction ***ID: [9c542c7e6f31d313ba637ef95c7a6fc125ab0a0f7ea2e8a790babfac22a3df57](https://blockchain.info/search?search=9c542c7e6f31d313ba637ef95c7a6fc125ab0a0f7ea2e8a790babfac22a3df57)***

Comment: What software are you using for your main wallet?

Answer (score 1):

Did you maybe use a very low fee? In that case your wallet may have rebroadcasted the tx while other nodes dont relay it because of too low fee.

I expect you have the mnemonic to recover the breadwallet saved somewhere. Maybe try to deinstall breadwallet and reinstall it using your mnemonic and see what it then shows?

Comment: ok it worked it said the transaction is invalid

Comment: and apparently my purchase wasn't actually refunded, so it probably was a problem with the wallet not being synced